# What is the best way to secure an url?

Tags: security, design-patterns

I develloping a simple website using spring-mvc. The question is what is the best way to secure an url?
For example, i have users and notes. Users can only edit/delete their owns notes.
A user edit a note with the link as localhost/note/edit/1

but i dont want other users to just change the id parameter and see others notes.

how dow you secure url in those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you need to check at the beginning of your edit page that the userID of the logged in person matches that of the owner of the data.

Comment: yeah, that is the simple way, i thought maybe there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Spring and you want your authorization decisions based on user ID, you should read up on [Spring Access Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

> To use expressions to secure individual URLs, you would first need to set the use-expressions attribute in the  element to true. Spring Security will then expect the access attributes of the  elements to contain Spring EL expressions. The expressions should evaluate to a boolean, defining whether access should be allowed or not.

But there are a lot of other ways to deal with authorization.  Don't get in the habit of assuming that user ID is the best way to make these decisions.  Read ["From ABAC to ZBAC"](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2009/HPL-2009-30.html) to learn about alternatives.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank for your answer, i will try to use this.

Comment: @stunaz, yw.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: too hard, complex to configure